# Enable next 7day in datepicker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I have implemented date picker in swift. I want to enable the date for next 7 day in calendar.How its is Possible.

Comment: This might be helpful, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date

Answer (score 0):

You can set a maximum date within a `UIDatePicker` like this:

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

// set the start date to today if you don't want to allow dates in the past
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()

// calculate +7 days
let next7Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())

//set maximum date
datePicker.maximumDate = next7Days
```

this will only allow to chose a date within the next 7 days